# How to parse JUnit result xml file and get testcase in java code?

Tags: java, xml, junit, ant, junit5

Implemented **dymanic** JUnit5 test using @TestFactory in class **Test_XyzDymanic**, method **testXyzDymanicallly** and custom Suite.xml to add multiple test cases which is being parsed at run time.

Based on cases in Suite.xml two maps are being fetched **mapExpected** and **mapAcutal** which is being compared as **assertIterableEquals**(mapExpected.entrySet(), mapAcutal.entrySet())

Junit is being called using **Ant** build and saved output in **result.xml**.

After execution some test cases are being failed (of course), Junit print only one line on console which is not not enough to know the cause.
So, have **ReportGenerator** which generates excel file based on slimier argument as in test case of junit.

***Query:*** 
For failed test case want to run **ReportGenerator** but don't know how to read failed test cases from **result.xml** in Java code.
Does Junit provide any class and parsing method to read **result.xml** in predefined PoJo? Or can we read and send as arguments from ant?

Ant targets:

```
<target name="test-dynamic" depends="test-compile" description="Run JUnit tests">
    <junit printsummary="true" haltonerror="no" haltonfailure="no" dir="${test.bin}" fork="true">
        <sysproperty key="suite" value="${suite.xml}" />
        <classpath refid="junit5.jars" />

        <test name="Test_XyzDymanic" outfile="${result}" failureproperty="test.failed">
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <formatter usefile="false" type="brief" />
        </test>
    </junit>
</target>

<target name="fail-report">
    <echo message="One or more test(s) failed. Generating faliur analysis report..." />
    <java classname="report.ReportGenerator" failonerror="no"/>
</target>
```

result.xml:

```
    ...
    <property name="sun.arch.data.model" value="32" />
  </properties>
  <testcase classname=")" name="Case: default case(testXyzDymanicallly" time="10.245">
    <failure message="iterable contents differ at index [75], expected: &lt;PropX.ShortName=NameXyz&gt; but was: &lt;PropX.ShortName=NameAbc&gt;" type="junit.framework.AssertionFailedError">junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: iterable contents differ at index [75], expected: &lt;PropX.ShortName=NameXyz&gt; but was: &lt;PropX.ShortName=NameAbc&gt;
    at Test_XyzDynamic.lambda$null$2(Test_XyzDynamic.java:41)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
</failure>
  </testcase>
```

ReportGenerator

```
class ReportGenerator{
    main(String args){}
    generate(){}
  }
```

***Tried:***

result.xml:

```
<property name="sun.arch.data.model" value="32" />
  </properties>
  <testcase classname=")" name="testcase1" time="9.596" />
  <testcase classname=")" name="testcase2" time="5.702">
    <failure message="msg1" type="type1">
    desc 11111
</failure>
  </testcase>
  <testcase classname=")" name="testcase3" time="5.656">
    <failure message="msg2" type="type2">
    desc 22222
</failure>
  </testcase>
  <testcase classname="junit.framework.JUnit4TestCaseFacade" name="JUnit Vintage" time="0.003" />
```

Ant:

```
<xmlproperty file="result.xml" keeproot="false" />
<target name="main">
    <echo>1. ${testcase}</echo>
    <echo>2. ${testcase(name)}</echo>
    <echo>3. ${testcase.failure}</echo>
    <echo>4. ${testcase.failure(type)}</echo>
    <echo>5. ${testcase.failure(message)}</echo>
</target>
```

output:

```
main:
     [echo] 1. ,
     [echo] 2. testcase1,testcase2,testcase3,JUnit Vintage
     [echo] 3. desc 11111,desc 22222
     [echo] 4. type1,type2
     [echo] 5. msg1,msg2
```

**Query**:
In console output, echo 2 has `testcase1,testcase2,testcase3,JUnit Vintage` but I want `testcase2,testcase3` because only these two testcases has failure tag as per the result.xml.

Comment: Native Ant has the `xmlproperty` task, which parses the attributes and inner text of an XML file into project properties. If you need to do something more advanced, there's the third party `xmltask` http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/

Comment: Thanks @CAustin, I have edited the question with my try as per your suggestion but still have a query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing effort of reading xml in `ant`, sending file to main class as argument and parsing file like any other xml and process required values.